# php application randomly log's out unexpectedly

Tags: php, session, logging, logout

I have made a website where people can create an account and post information to the database. I have made a personal account for testing.

But whenever i log in and access a certain page or perform a post on the website, it automatically log's itself out, i check the session and cookie variables and their empty.

But on different occasions when i log in and make a post it works just fine. (This usually happens when i log in again or log out). I have used session_save_path with no prevail, mainly because my host wont let me change directories as it is always /tmp.

Login (log.php)

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = sha1($_POST['p']);
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($e == "" || $p == ""){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($p != $db_pass_str){
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
        } else {
            // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE); 
            // UPDATE THEIR "IP" AND "LASTLOGIN" FIELDS
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo $db_username;
            exit();
        }
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

Login Javascript

```
function login(){
            var e = _("emai").value;
            var p = _("passwor").value;
            if(e == "" || p == ""){
                _("statu").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
            } else {
                _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
                _("statu").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
                var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "log.php");
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                        if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                            _("statu").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
                            _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                        } else {
                            window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
            }
        }
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Set Session data to an empty array
$_SESSION = array();
// Expire their cookie files
if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])) {
    setcookie("id", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
    setcookie("user", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
    setcookie("pass", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
 }
// Destroy the session variables
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();


// Double check to see if their sessions exists
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location: message.php?msg=Error:_Logout_Failed");
} else {
    header("location: http://www.uasa.co/home");
    exit();
} 
?>
```

Check if the user is logged in on each page- "include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
// Files that inculde this file at the very top would NOT require 
// connection to database or session_start(), be careful.
// Initialize some vars
$user_ok = false;
$log_id = "";
$log_username = "";
$log_password = "";
// User Verify function
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
    $sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
    $log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);
    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
} else if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])){
    $_SESSION['userid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_COOKIE['id']);
    $_SESSION['username'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['pass']);
    $log_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $log_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];
    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    if($user_ok == true){
        // Update their lastlogin datetime field
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$log_id' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Im sorry this is lot. But any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nothing jumping out at me.  It might help to see what comes from:

```
"include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
```

Could you check the config.ini file and check look for "session.cookie_lifetime = 0".  If that is not a zero, a number means seconds.

Verify that all your db stuff is there - ip address etc.  I have been on servers where /tmp gets mysteriously cleaned due to bad configuration.  I would also use firebug to double check the ajax calls.  -- Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for the advice ill look into a bit more.